# Is there any approach to make Join with JPA2 criteria API like this?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria

I'm in trouble with JPA2 criteria API. Is there any approach to make smth like this with JPA2 criteria API:

*SELECT* **t1.id** *FROM* Table1 t1 *INNER JOIN* Table2 t2 *ON* (t1.id = t2.id)

With these rules:

1. table1 hasn't table2 reference
2. table2 has table1 reference
3. the result should be table1 ids

I'm consfused with JPA2 criteria API Root. How to create join in this situation? Should I use two ROOT's : one for JOIN, another for SELECT? please response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using where**
You could do a usual JPQL cross-product join:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 WHERE t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

**JPA support for right joins**
JPA does not support right join queries. From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/JoinType.html):

> Right outer joins and right outer fetch joins are not required to be
>   supported in Java Persistence 2.0. Applications that use RIGHT join
>   types will not be portable.

**Native SQL query**
So another option would be using a native SQL query.

```
SELECT Table1.id FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table2.t1_id = Table1.id
```

Comment: In SQL native all sql statements work; including UNION.

Comment: btw, in native SQL query : table is real table name and fields from DB or it is entity in java & it's fields?

Comment: I have updated the native sql query to be more clear; these are table names

Answer (score 1):

The JPQL query would simply be

```
select e1.id from Entity2 e2 join e2.entity1 e1
```

With the criteria API, it would look like this (untested. I hate this API):

```
CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Entity2> e2 = cq.from(Entity2.class);
cq.select(e2.get(Entity2_.entity1).get(Entity1_.id));
```

Comment: so using JPQL is more simpler...what about API?

Comment: And does it support UNION?

Comment: union is not supported ny JPQL. What do you mean by "API"? The JPA2 Criteria API? You'd have to translate the above. But This API is extremely cumbersome and produces hard to maintain code. Why use that rather than dead-simple JPQL?

Comment: I need to make 2 select query per one request (it's more efficient than making 2 calls to DB). So I am thinking about union. It works fine in plain SQL. To sum up, I have 2 cases on same entity. These cases are filled up with a lot of joins, but selected fields are the same in both cases.

Comment: JPA doesn't support unions. End of story. So if you want a union, use a native query.

Comment: Ok, native query, i am coming!

Comment: ok i accept it, your comments are more efficient than your answer (because it helped me to realize my situation more better)